# Android On Demand delivery data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-bundle

I'm trying to create a project with on demand delivery.

I created a simple project with one activity which contains a button that will open another application which is added as a module.

I followed the instruction from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/on-demand-delivery). But when I try to compile the project, this error appears.

Data binding is enabled in both modules and I don't know why this error appears.

```
Execution failed for task ':rewrite:dataBindingExportFeatureInfoDebug'.  
java.util.NoSuchElementException (no error message)
```

Comment: Can you share your sample project, because this is strange error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the steps on [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/at-install-delivery). The `feature module` didn't have a dependency with the `base module`.

To solve the problem I added in the `build.gradle` of the `feature module` next line:

```
 implementation project(':app')
```